# PostgreSQL batch inserts fail silent randomly

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, amazon-rds, pentaho

I have been using [Kettle](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/) to import data from a SQL Server to PostgreSQL on AWS RDS and when I was enabling all of my foreign key constraints I realized that data was missing, often in the even hundreds.

But checking the log of the Kettle job, it seems to be doing all read and writes correctly from a table of `1923` entries

```
2017/02/26 21:36:42 - Table output.5 - Finished processing (I=0, O=240, R=240, W=240, U=0, E=0)
2017/02/26 21:36:42 - Table output.3 - Finished processing (I=0, O=240, R=240, W=240, U=0, E=0)
2017/02/26 21:36:42 - Table output.7 - Finished processing (I=0, O=240, R=240, W=240, U=0, E=0)
2017/02/26 21:36:42 - Table output.6 - Finished processing (I=0, O=240, R=240, W=240, U=0, E=0)
2017/02/26 21:36:42 - Table output.1 - Finished processing (I=0, O=241, R=241, W=241, U=0, E=0)
2017/02/26 21:36:42 - Table output.2 - Finished processing (I=0, O=241, R=241, W=241, U=0, E=0)
2017/02/26 21:36:42 - Table output.4 - Finished processing (I=0, O=240, R=240, W=240, U=0, E=0)
2017/02/26 21:36:42 - Table output.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=241, R=241, W=241, U=0, E=0)
```

But when running the query count on Postgres I get `1423` entries, and similar behavior on maybe 10% of all tables I have transferred.

As I don't have any prior experience in neither Kettle nor Postgres, what is it that can cause this issue?

Comment: Check the PostgreSQL logs?

Comment: I checked the ones i have on RDS, but nothing strange in those

Comment: Could you try to disable "Use batch update for inserts" on your table output to test? It might be slower but sometimes reveals a better error message.

Comment: Thank you both for taking your time craig-ringer and tom-v (can only mention one)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the author of the script i used ([sqlserver2pgsql](https://github.com/dalibo/sqlserver2pgsql)) we realized it was a (new) issue with how Kettle handled parallel output table truncates.

https://github.com/dalibo/sqlserver2pgsql/issues/57#issuecomment-282675275

What happened was, and the reason i only lacked even hundreds of data, that the output job in some cases did run truncate after one or more workers already had done inserts on the table